# How to join 2 MySql tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. `Table1` contains products inventory in store #1 and 
`Table2` contains products inventory in store #2

```
Table1:
upc  | description   | QtyOnHand1
4050 | cantaloupe    | 10
4131 | fuji apples   | 20
5033 | strawberries  | 5

Table2
upc  | description | QtyOnHand2
4050 | cantaloupe  | 15
4131 | fuji apples | 23
4121 | aprictos    | 13
```

What select statement should I use to get the following result.

```
upc  | description  | QtyOnHand1 | QtyOnHand2
4050 | cantaloupe   | 10         | 15
4131 | fuji apples  | 20         | 23
5033 | strawberries | 5          | null
4121 |  apricots    | null       | 13
```

Comment: At least you should have tried something,no matter how wrong.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You are getting downvoted here because the expectation here as pointed out by @Mihai is that you show what you've tried.  See this page for tips on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which MySQL does not support.  A FULL OUTER JOIN will return rows from both of your tables which will allow you to return the rows that don't exist in both in your data that will be for `strawberries` and `apricots`.

You can simulate a FULL OUTER JOIN using a UNION query similar to the following:

```
SELECT t1.upc,
  t1.description,
  t1.QtyOnHand1,
  t2.QtyOnHand2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
  ON t1.upc= t2.upc
UNION
SELECT t2.upc,
  t2.description,
  t1.QtyOnHand1,
  t2.QtyOnHand2
FROM table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 
  ON t1.upc = t2.upc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb21/4).

Another way this could be written would be to get the DISTINCT list of each `upc` from the two tables and then use a LEFT JOIN to your tables:

```
select d.upc,
  coalesce(t1.description, t2.description) description,
  t1.QtyOnHand1,
  t2.QtyOnHand2
from
(
  select upc from table1
  union 
  select upc from table2
) d
left join table1 t1
  on d.upc = t1.upc
left join table2 t2
  on d.upc = t2.upc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb21/3).

As a side note, you might want to reconsider creating separate tables for each `store`, this is going to be a maintenance nightmare when you have 100 stores, etc.

Comment: Alternatively it could be UNION ALL, then GROUP BY.

Answer (score -4):

you'll use a Join statement
something like this:

```
select table1.upc, table1.description, table1.QtyOnHand1, table2.QtyOnHand2 
from Table1, table2 
left join table2 on table1.upc = table2.upc;
```

Comment: You should either use implicit joins or explicit ones (actually, you should always use explicit joins), but not both